# form doesn't appear and how to remove <li> in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, form-control, django-file-upload

i have problem. why my form doesn't show except i clicked submit button. is that any problem with my code?

here's my html code :

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <button type="submit" class="dsnupload">
                                <i class="large material-icons" style="font-size: 50pt; margin-top: 10px;">audiotrack</i>
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Insert file audio (mp3)</p>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{form}}
                            </button>
                          </form>
```

form.py :

```
from django import forms

class Audio_store(forms.Form):
    record=forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```

views.py :

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
        return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
    else:
          return render(request, "homepage.html")
```

at the second orange button on the left (insert file audio) there's text :

> record :
>
> - this field is required.

[image: web]

i want to remove that text, please help me.

Comment: Your form doesn't render because you aren't pass it in the context in case of a GET request (The else block).

Comment: how to pass it? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Hello @Monana try to return this line `return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})`  inside your else block instead of this `return render(request, "homepage.html")`

Comment: error, UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment. Request Method: GET @AnkitTiwari how to change to POST?

Comment: Hello @Monana check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to read about python variable [scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

```
def homepage(request):
    form = Audio_store()
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
          return redirect("your_sccess_url")
    return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
```

if your form valid it's good practice to redirect user to new [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)